# Serializer for custom type 'janusgraph.RelationIdentifier' not found

Tags: spring-boot, gremlin, janusgraph, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

Janus Server config

```
serializers:
   - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
   - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
```

Java/Spring boot config

```
@Bean
public Cluster cluster() {
    return Cluster.build()
            .addContactPoint(dbUrl)
            .port(dbPort)
            .serializer(new GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1())
            .maxConnectionPoolSize(5)
            .maxInProcessPerConnection(1)
            .maxSimultaneousUsagePerConnection(10)
            .create();
}
```

Getting the following error,

```
Caused by: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.SerializationException: java.io.IOException: Serializer for custom type 'janusgraph.RelationIdentifier' not found
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.binary.ResponseMessageSerializer.readValue(ResponseMessageSerializer.java:59) ~[gremlin-driver-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1.deserializeResponse(GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1.java:180) ~[gremlin-driver-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.handler.WebSocketGremlinResponseDecoder.decode(WebSocketGremlinResponseDecoder.java:47) ~[gremlin-driver-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.handler.WebSocketGremlinResponseDecoder.decode(WebSocketGremlinResponseDecoder.java:35) ~[gremlin-driver-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
```

Note: I didn't define the schema. Migrating the code from AWS NEPTUNE (working code) to JanusGraph.

Any help on why I am getting the above error?

Get queries are working and a few mutations queries also working,...

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have only defined the serializer for JanusGraph types on the server, but not on the client side. You also need to add the `JanusGraphIoRegistry` on the client side.

This can be done like this:

```java
TypeSerializerRegistry typeSerializerRegistry = TypeSerializerRegistry.build()
    .addRegistry(JanusGraphIoRegistry.instance())
    .create();

Cluster.build()
    .addContactPoint(dbUrl)
    .port(dbPort)
    .serializer(new GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1(typeSerializerRegistry))
    .maxConnectionPoolSize(5)
    .maxInProcessPerConnection(1)
    .maxSimultaneousUsagePerConnection(10)
    .create();
```

or you can alternatively use a config file for it which simplifies the code down to:

```java
import static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal;

GraphTraversalSource g = traversal().withRemote("conf/remote-graph.properties");
```

(I have already created the `GraphTraversalSource` here because the client is directly created internally by `withRemote()`.)

This is also described in the JanusGraph documentation [under *Connecting from Java*](https://docs.janusgraph.org/master/interactions/connecting/java/#getting-started-with-janusgraph-and-gremlin-java). Note that I've linked to a version of the docs for the upcoming 1.0.0 release because the documentation for the latest released version right now still uses Gryo instead of GraphBinary. But you can still use this with JanusGraph 0.6 already and it also makes sense to use GraphBinary instead of Gryo, because support for Gryo will be dropped in version 1.0.0.

The config file `conf/remote-graph.properties` looks then like this (also taken from the JanusGraph documentation):

```yaml
hosts: [localhost]
port: 8182
serializer: { 
    className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1,
    config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
```

You can also specify the various options that you are currently specifying via the builder. This configuration is documented [in the TinkerPop reference docs](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.5.2/reference/#gremlin-java-configuration).